# Database updating, but GridView remains unchanged

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, gridview

I've got my code to delete rows out of the database when the user clicks on the Delete button in my GridView, but the GridView isn't updating to reflect the new data changes.

Here's my code:

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdQuestions" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" CellSpacing="10"
         PagerSettings-Visible="true">
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="aspNetHeader" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionID" HeaderText="QID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModuleID" HeaderText="Mod #" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionText" HeaderText="Question" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CorrectAnswer" HeaderText="Answer" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerNote" HeaderText="Note" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkEdit" Text="Edit"></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkDelete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# eval("QuestionID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

Protected Sub grdQuestions_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grdQuestions.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Delete" Then

        sql = "delete from tmp_Questions where QuestionID = " & e.CommandArgument
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, d.SQLConnection)

        d.SQLConnection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        d.SQLConnection.Close()

        GetModuleData()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub grdQuestions_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles grdQuestions.RowDeleting
    GetModuleData()
End Sub

Private Sub GetModuleData()
    ' ddlModules is a drop down where the user can select a module to filter questions by.
    Dim selid As Integer = ddlModules.SelectedItem.Value
    sql = "select QuestionID, ModuleID, LEFT(QuestionText, charindex(' ', QuestionText, 30)) as QuestionText, CorrectAnswer," & vbCrLf & _
        "AnswerNote from tmp_Questions" & vbCrLf & _
        "where ModuleID = " & selid & vbCrLf & _
        "order by ModuleID"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, d.SQLConnection)
    cmd.CommandText = sql

    QuestionAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
    QuestionAdapter.Fill(QuestionData)

    If QuestionData.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        grdQuestions.DataSource = QuestionData
        grdQuestions.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for having a look!

**EDIT 1:**
Did some stepping through the code and found that `e.CommandArgument` is not getting a value in `grdQuestions_RowCommand`

**EDIT 1 (Revised):**
The fact that `e.CommandArgument` wasn't getting a value was my mistake. I'd changed the way it's value was being assigned without removing the previous method.
The code runs through `grdQuestions_RowCommand` and then goes into `grdQuestions_RowDeleting` and then executes `GetModuleData`.
I have a feeling that to view changes to the grid, a PostBack might be required, but I've removed all DataBinding to an `If Not IsPostBack Then` block because the alternative caused problems with the DropDownList whose selection is used as a reference to populate the grid (ddlModules selected the Module whose Questions will display in the grid).

Comment: What does "GridView isn't updating to reflect the new data changes" mean? Do you get an exception, have you debugged to ensure that  `grdQuestions.DataBind()` gets called? Is your DataTable/DataSet being cleared before it will be filled by the DataAdapter(`ClearBeforeFill`)?

Comment: @Tim please see new edit, apologies for lack of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have neither specified the `CommandName="Edit"` for `lnkEdit` nor `CommandName="Delete"` for `lnkDelete`.

*I have a feeling that to view changes to the grid, a PostBack might be required*

Of course, a postback must occur and the GridView  must be databound to it's DataSource again after you've deleted the record. But that postback has been already occured when the user clicked the delete-link and the `grdQuestions_RowDeleting` has been handled.
Debug and ensure that the record gets deleted and **afterwards** the GridView gets databound again.

Comment: The row IS being removed from the database. The problem is that I can't seem to get the GridView to update. There are no errors in the code that are being reported.

Comment: How can the  row be removed when the code where it will be deleted is never called? How can it be removed when you say that `e.CommandArgument` "is not getting a value" therefore the SQL is malformed?

Comment: I hadn't removed less efficient logic from the code before the code you see now, that was wrecking the `e.CommandArgument` situation. Having rectified that, the row is now being removed from the database.

Comment: @Logan: Delete the record from the database, then `DataBind` the GridView to reflect the changes in the model. You don't need an additonal postback, only keep this order.

Comment: I understand the order, which is why `GetModuleData` is being called in `grdQuestions_RowCommand` after the sql delete is being executed. The grid still isn't updating.

Comment: @Logan: What i've already written: Have you debugged to ensure that `grdQuestions.DataBind()` gets called? Is your DataTable/DataSet being cleared before it will be filled by the DataAdapter(`ClearBeforeFill=True`)? Where are the DataAdapter and the DataSet initialized, why are they class members and don't have  only method scope? That is a source for such issues and needless since variables are anyway disposed at the end of [Page's lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).